# Performing multiple computations with Hadoop Map Reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a map reduce program for finding the min/max for 2 separate properties for each year.  This works, for the most part, using a single node cluster in hadoop.  Here is my currently setup:

```
public class MaxTemperatureReducer extends
        Reducer<Text, Stats, Text, Stats> {

    private Stats result = new Stats();

    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Stats> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int sum = 0;

        for (Stats value : values) {
            result.setMaxTemp(Math.max(maxValue, value.getMaxTemp()));
            result.setMinTemp(Math.min(minValue, value.getMinTemp()));
            result.setMaxWind(Math.max(maxValue, value.getMaxWind()));
            result.setMinWind(Math.min(minValue, value.getMinWind()));

            sum += value.getCount();
        }

        result.setCount(sum);

        context.write(key, result);
    }
}

public class MaxTemperatureMapper extends
        Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Stats> {

    private static final int MISSING = 9999;
    private Stats outStat = new Stats();

    @Override
    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String[] split = value.toString().split("\\s+");
        String year = split[2].substring(0, 4);
        int airTemperature;
        airTemperature = (int) Float.parseFloat(split[3]);

        outStat.setMinTemp((float)airTemperature);
        outStat.setMaxTemp((float)airTemperature);

        outStat.setMinWind(Float.parseFloat(split[12]));
        outStat.setMaxWind(Float.parseFloat(split[14]));
        outStat.setCount(1);

        context.write(new Text(year), outStat);
    }
}

public class MaxTemperatureDriver extends Configured implements Tool {
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err
                    .println("Usage: MaxTemperatureDriver <input path> <outputpath>");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        Job job = new Job();
        job.setJarByClass(MaxTemperatureDriver.class);
        job.setJobName("Max Temperature");

        job.setMapperClass(MaxTemperatureMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(MaxTemperatureReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(MaxTemperatureReducer.class);



        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Stats.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
        boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
        return success ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MaxTemperatureDriver driver = new MaxTemperatureDriver();
        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(driver, args);
        System.exit(exitCode);

    }
 }
```

Currently it only prints the Min/Max for the temp and windspeed for each year.  I am sure it is a simple implementation but cannot find a answer anywhere.  I want to try and find the top 5 min/max for each year.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume the following signature for your Stats class.

```
/* the stats class need to be a writable, the below is just a demo*/
public class Stats {

public float getTemp() {
    return temp;
}
public void setTemp(float temp) {
    this.temp = temp;
}
public float getWind() {
    return wind;
}
public void setWind(float wind) {
    this.wind = wind;
}
private float temp;
private float wind;
}
```

With this, let us change the reducer as below.

```
SortedSet<Float> tempSetMax = new TreeSet<Float>();
        SortedSet<Float> tempSetMin = new TreeSet<Float>();
        SortedSet<Float> windSetMin = new TreeSet<Float>();
        SortedSet<Float> windSetMax = new TreeSet<Float>();
        List<Stats> values = new ArrayList<Float>();
        for (Stats value : values) {

            float temp = value.getTemp();
            float wind = value.getWind();

            if (tempSetMax.size() < 5) {
                tempSetMax.add(temp);
            } else {
                float currentMinValue = tempSetMax.first();
                if (temp > currentMinValue) {
                    tempSetMax.remove(currentMinValue);
                    tempSetMax.add(temp);
                }
            }
            if (tempSetMin.size() < 5) {
                tempSetMin.add(temp);
            } else {
                float currentMaxValue = tempSetMin.last();
                if (temp < currentMaxValue) {
                    tempSetMax.remove(currentMaxValue);
                    tempSetMax.add(temp);
                }
            }

            if (windSetMin.size() < 5) {
                windSetMin.add(wind);
            } else {

                float currentMaxValue = windSetMin.last();
                if (wind < currentMaxValue) {
                    windSetMin.remove(currentMaxValue);
                    windSetMin.add(temp);
                }

            }
            if (windSetMax.size() < 5) {
                windSetMax.add(wind);
            } else {

                float currentMinValue = windSetMax.first();
                if (wind > currentMinValue) {
                    windSetMax.remove(currentMinValue);
                    windSetMax.add(temp);
                }

            }
        }
```

Now you can write to context the `toString()` of each list, or you can create a custom writable. In my code, please change the `Stats` according to your requirement. It needs to be a `Writable`. The above is just for demonstrating the example flow.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/adamjshook/mapreducepatterns/blob/master/MRDP/src/main/java/mrdp/ch3/TopTenDriver.java) is the code from the MR Design Patterns Book to get the top 10. There is also code for other MR design patterns in the same GitHub location.